# How to set up a separate environment for QtCreator on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: install, xcode, development

I try to move from Linux to macOS Big Sur with my app development. The app is in an early development stage and there's no platform-dependent code. I am using QtCreator as an IDE and under Linux everything works - the game loop and rendering run smoothly, everything works as expected, as described in the Qt documentation. But when I try to build and run this code in the QtCreator under macOS Big Sur there are problems that should not occur (the app builds but when I try to run the code, it doesn't work as expected - even the basics explained in the Qt documentation fail to work as described). I don't think that there's a problem with my code - I wrote a simpler example that uses features I need but it fails to behave as described in Qt documentation too.

The only thing that I can think of that could cause the problem is sdk version - while building the project, QtCreator informs me that it is not tested under the sdk version 11.1 and I should switch to 10.15. How can I set the sdk version for QtCreator/qmake only? I don't want every other app to use the old sdk version, I want only QtCreator/qmake to build my app using the old version. Is there a way to do this?

So to conclude, I want to set up a local/separate environment for QtCreator than for other apps.   Creation of a new user account could work for me? If yes, how to downgrade/switch sdk version properly for only one account?